# GMModel - how do I use this to predict a label's data?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, gaussian

I've made a GMModel using fitgmdist. The idea is to produce two gaussian distributions on the data and use that to predict their labels. How can I determine if a future data point fits into one of those distributions? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of a GMModel?

```
clear;
load C:\Users\Daniel\Downloads\data1 data;


% Mixed Gaussian
GMModel = fitgmdist(data(:, 1:4),2)
```

Produces

```
GMModel = 

Gaussian mixture distribution with 2 components in 4 dimensions
Component 1:
Mixing proportion: 0.509709
Mean:    2.3254   -2.5373    3.9288    0.4863

Component 2:
Mixing proportion: 0.490291
Mean:    2.5161   -2.6390    0.8930    0.4833
```

Edit:

```
clear;
load C:\Users\Daniel\Downloads\data1 data;



% Mixed Gaussian
GMModel = fitgmdist(data(:, 1:4),2);


P = posterior(GMModel, data(:, 1:4));
X = round(P)

blah = X(:, 1)
dah = data(:, 5)

Y = max(mean(blah == dah), mean(~blah == dah))
```

Comment: "How can I determine if a future data point fits into one of those distributions?" - Compute the probability of the data point belonging to either component using the estimated PDF of the `GMModel`.

Comment: How do I determine that?

Comment: `gmdistribution` has the method [`posterior`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.posterior.html) for that.

Comment: Thanks a ton.

I'm getting extremely poor performance - ranging from 51% accuracy to 95% accuracy. I posted my code above. Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: No problem. Classification is a tricky problem, it's hard to say what might be the problem. I'm more or less guessing here. Your code for training the model seems ok. One thing to consider is the "Gaussianity" of the actual data in your classes. Even if there are two classes, it may not be sufficient to represent each with just a single GMM component.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you round the posterior values. Here is what I would do after fitting a mixture model.

`P = posterior(GMModel, data(:, 1:4)); 
[~,Y] = max(P,[],2);`

Now Y contains the labels that is index of which Gaussian the data belongs in-terms of maximum aposterior (MAP). Important thing to do is to align the labels before evaluating the classification error. Since renumbering might happen, i.e., Gaussian component 1 in the true might be component 2 in the  clustering produced and so on.  May be that why you are getting varying accuracy ranging from 51% accuracy to 95% accuracy, in addition to other subtle problems.